# How to name download file

Tags: url, download, filenames

I'm calling a web service to download a file, but it always assigns a generic name to the download.  Every file I download has the same name.

So I appended "/filename.pdf?a=true"  to the end of the URL as follows:

```
 http://localhost/api/node/content/b52b3136-1cf0-48f2-a109-676a16015612/myfilename.pdf?a=true
```

Now on Firefox, the file downloads with the desired: myfilename.pdf.
But this isn't working on IE or Chrome.

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a header: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=my_file_name.pdf`

Will force a download (instead of an inline display) and set the file name. If you do **not** force a file name, but allow inline display (via PDF browser plugin) the filename is meaningless, which is, why it is often ignored by browsers.